# pandas: timestamp conversion Type error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have the following code:

```
import datatime as dt

print(type(row['my_timestamp']))
current_date = dt.date.fromtimestamp(row['my_timestamp'])
```

where `row` is a pandas data frame row.

But got the following output and error:

```
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-95348c1ae55f> in <module>()
     10     print(type(row['my_timestamp']))
---> 11     current_date = dt.date.fromtimestamp(row['my_timestamp'])

TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Any idea what I might have missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromtimestamp` expects the epoch time in seconds as an integer. `pandas` already has the method `.date` to output `datetime.date` type.

```
current_date = row['my_timestamp'].date()
```